# can I implement gestures with twilio programmable chat?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am creating a web chat and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of implementing a gesture such as raising one's hand. Can I do this with twilio programmable chat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you were building a group chat using [Twilio's Programmable Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat) and you wanted users to be able to send an action like raising a hand instead of a full message each time, you could definitely achieve this.

When you send a [message to the chat channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/message-resource#message-properties) you don't need to set a message body and you can set an arbitrary JSON object of attributes. To implement raising a hand, you could include a specific attribute (`{handRaised: true}` perhaps) that your interface could then read to visually display that the user wants help instead of rendering it as a message within the channel.

Does that help at all?